# How to do realtime highcharts in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, real-time, sidekiq

I want to build realtime highcharts, and i have user table added sidekiq worker which fetches user_table every 5 minutes and i want it show my users data in real time in my rails application?

Below i have static data, how to retrieve data dynamically from database?

In View:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
          type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'User balance',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Users']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Balance'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '$'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
  series: [{

            name: User'',
            data: [<%= @user.sum('equivalent_sum')%>]
        }]
    });
});
```

In Controller:

```
@user = User.where('balance > ?', 0)
```

Comment: @Substantial I added the code, i have static data, don't know how to start with dynamic data

Comment: Use a `setInterval` function to make an AJAX call every 5 minutes.  Retrieve your data and use `setData` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) or `addPoint` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint) to update your series...